# How to load css as static in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates

Hi I have the following structure in my project:

```
myapp
├── app
│   ├── app
|   |   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── [...]
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── my_test.html
│   └── app2
│       ├── [...]
├── statics
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   └── static_root
```

and I want to use the bootstrap.min.css in the base.html (which looks currently like this):

```
{% load staticfiles %}                                                         
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                
<html>                                                                         
    <head>                                                                       
    {% block head %}                                                           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statics/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    {% endblock head %}                                                        
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                        

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics', 'static_root')                 

STATICFILES_DIR = {                                                            
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics', 'bootstrap'),                            
}
```

so how I have to chance it that it works because in this version it does not work (`Page not found at /statics/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously this `(Page not found at /statics/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css).` won't work. Your static_url is `/static`. Try to check on `/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Also I recommend using [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#static) template tag

```
{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}
```

Comment: I meant reversing urls for static files. Thanks for pointing out  I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the FineManual ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake. Static files should be name as '**static**' not '**statics **'
Because in your settings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```